# PHPMailer is sending with incorrect "date"

Tags: codeigniter, smtp, phpmailer, sendmail

I have an issue with my code.  All emails are sent with same date "31-mar-2017".  here's the mail notification.

```
Return-Path: <xxxxxx@gmail.com>
Received: from ip-172-31-29-190 (ec2-xx-xxx-xx.xx.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com. [xx-xxx-xx.xx])
        by smtp.googlemail.com with ESMTPSA id a81sm7358557pfe.32.2017.11.02.08.27.05
        for <xxxxxxxx@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Thu, 02 Nov 2017 08:27:06 -0700 (PDT)
Date: Fri, 31 Mar 2017 21:40:26 +0530
```

Can't figure out what the problem is...  Appreciate your help.

### Edit-1:

I have inherited this code.  Following config is found:

```
defined('SMTP_HOST')   ? null : define("SMTP_HOST", "ssl://smtp.googlemail.com");
defined('SMTP_PORT')   ? null : define("SMTP_PORT", "465");
defined('SMTP_SECURE')   ? null : define("SMTP_SECURE", "tls");
```

### Edit-2:

Our implementation is similar to [How to build an email queue with PHPmailer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45441442/how-to-build-an-email-queue-with-phpmailer).  ie., all emails are written to a `jobs` table and then picked up for processing.

The issue is emails are not working on my local and Test servers.  However, they work on Production :(

It's becoming a herculean task to figure out why these things are not working on local and Test servers when the sample code https://github.com/phpmailer/phpmailer works perfectly fine on both.

This issue need to be solved prior to looking to the original issue posted here.  No emails in the mail queue.  Any pointers??

Comment: Have you checked the server date-time ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31309536/how-to-set-time-zone-in-codeigniter

Comment: server date-time is fine.  
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata') is also set 

require "modules/Database.class.php";
require "modules/constants.php";
//require "vendor/swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php";
require "vendor/autoload.php";
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
global $db,$mail,$log;
// create a log channel
$mail = new PHPMailer;
//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP

Comment: Don't post details of question or code in comments. Post them in your question itself.

Comment: How do you expect us to comment on your code if you don't post it? One obvious problem is that you can't use `tls` encryption mode on port 465; it should be 587 or 25, but the inclusion of the `ssl://` prefix on your `Host` value is overriding that which is why it isn't breaking. Also why are you loading both SwiftMailer **and** PHPMailer? Pick one!

Comment: @Synchro I noticed that `sendmail` daemon was started on 31-mar-2017.  Also,  **Date** header is not set on the generated email.  

As per `phpmailer` documentation, system date will be picked up if **Date** header is empty. However, it appears that daemon start date & time is stamped on generated email.  How should this be addressed?  Thanks

Comment: PHPMailer sets the date header automatically, unless you override it (by setting the `MessageDate` property). Your mail server may also be doing something with it.

Comment: Thanks @Synchro.  The issue is solved after setting the `clock` with correct timezone as per this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-time.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the issue was not related to `phpmailer` or associated configuration.

Even setting the `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata')` didn't help.

At the end, updating system `clock` and rebooting the server as per [Setting the Time for Your Linux Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-time.html) fixed the *incorrect date* issue.

Regarding emails not working on Test Server, my predecessor used `supervisord` to handle these processes.  I had to just start that daemon as it wasn't part of `init.d`.

Thanks